# Method Annotated with @Scheduled is not working in spring boot application , when added as another dependency to another spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

We have spring boot app, which contains the one method annotated with `@Scheduled`, in a class. I created jar file from this spring boot app and added this as dependency in another spring boot application, when I started this second main spring boot application, I expected the method annotated with `@Scheduled`, to execute every minute (I configured like in that application.yml of the first spring boot app). But this not running like this. When I tested the first spring boot app along as app, it is working method is invoked every 1 minute, can any one help why the same method not working when I added as jar to another spring boot app.

Note : the second main spring boot app, does not contain any more classed expect one class annotated with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
```

can anyone please suggest why this is not working ?

Answer (score -1):

The bean/component that includes the `@Scheduled` doesn't get created. You either create the bean yourself or tell Spring where to look. E.g. by using `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: @msparser , i already added @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"<packages from jar spring boot app>", "<package name from main spring boot app>"}) , even then also method is not triggered